# ansible docker module: unsupported parameter docker_api_version

Tags: docker, ansible

Because of different Docker API versions on my machine and the target server, I have to specify the version in my task, as for https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/issues/705

Here's my task:

```
- name: stop the running container
  docker: 
    docker_api_version: 1.13
    image: my_image
    name: my_container
    state: absent
```

returns the error:

```
msg: unsupported parameter for module: docker_api_version
```

I'm using ansible 1.7.2, and the parameter appears in the documentation for 1.4 http://docs.ansible.com/docker_module.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for `docker_api_version` reads "added in Ansible 1.8". (See comments section on the page you linked http://docs.ansible.com/docker_module.html)